# Difficulty in installing Ubuntu

Tags: operating-system

Is there any way to convert MBR partition to GPT partition without any data loss while installing UBUNTU along with Windows 8.1 (dual boot)?
I am using Windows 8.1 with..

- Intel Core i3-4005U processor
- 4 GB RAM
- 64-bit operating system
- x64-based processor
  here is the image of the disk management..
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALs4q.png)

Comment: You should try to search for your answer at https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to move the data and then create a new partition by freeing up the space from the MBR partition.

Comment: This should have been a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: I apologize. I'm new here, so i am unfamiliar with the rules.

Comment: No problem, i suggest for future